# Triggering UltiSnips with enter

Tags: key-bindings, autocompletion, insert-mode, plugin-ultisnips, snippets

Is there any possible way to do expand trigger in UltiSnips with <kbd>enter</kbd>? I've tried `<Enter>`, `<Return>`, and `<CR>`. It works to trigger but doesn't work for new line. And I've tried to `<S-Enter>`, but vim doesn't seems like recognize that I press <kbd>Shift</kbd> button.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently Ultisnips only does this for tab as early adopters of the plugin complained that it broke supertab. It's worth asking the maintainer whether he'd be willing to fix this for `<CR>` too.

That being said, there is a workaround that's described in [the docs](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/blob/09876e008495e171f59ed8ce876666d5f8e16ee3/doc/UltiSnips.txt#L292):

```
let g:ulti_expand_or_jump_res = 0 "default value, just set once
function! Ulti_ExpandOrJump_and_getRes()
    call UltiSnips#ExpandSnippetOrJump()
    return g:ulti_expand_or_jump_res
endfunction

inoremap <CR> <C-R>=(Ulti_ExpandOrJump_and_getRes() > 0)?"":"\n"<CR>
```

Note that you probably don't want to use `<CR>` as your jump shortcut, as this would prevent you from filling in parts of a snippet with multi-line strings.

Comment: Works well but inserts two newlines when I hit enter. 
`inoremap <CR> <C-R>=(Ulti_ExpandOrJump_and_getRes() > 0)?"":""<CR>`
seems to fix that